# How to create and append text in the body using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, which isn't working, where I tried to create and append some text in the body. I don't know what i missed out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Number guessing game</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var par = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode("fhsgdjrs hgrtsfya");
  par.appendChild(text);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Please reformat your question to ask a single specific question. Stackoverflow is not a site where we write code for you.

Comment: You have to append par to something, or log it. After creating the par, you just add some text to it, but dont do anythign with that after.

Comment: var par = document.createElement("p");

var text = document.createTextNode("This is a program");

par.appendChild(text);

What is the problem in above code. Output is not coming as " This is a program"

Answer (score 5):

You need to append the variable `par` (which has the element `<p>` that you created using JavaScript) to the body (tag `<body>` in HTML / code `document.body` in JavaScript) like the below code snippet:

```js
var par = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("fhsgdjrs hgrtsfya");
par.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(par);
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Number guessing game</title>
</head>
```

You can find an similar example (with a `<button>`) in [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp).

Here's your code with the added code line (`document.body.appendChild(par);`) to make it work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Number guessing game</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var par = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("fhsgdjrs hgrtsfya");
par.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(par);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want the output to be `My first Program` instead of `fhsgdjrs hgrtsfya`, then you have to change the code line where you create the text node:

```
var text = document.createTextNode("fhsgdjrs hgrtsfya");
```

Changing the string inside the method [`createTextNode`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createtextnode.asp) will change the output:

```
var text = document.createTextNode("My first Program");
```

The syntax is:

```
document.createTextNode( text )
```

The parameter text (type [string](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp)) is required as that's the text of the Text node.

Answer (score 3):

Append the created element `<p>` into the tag `<body>` like it's shown in the code below:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Number guessing game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var par = document.createElement("p"); //creating the paragraph element 
    var text = document.createTextNode("Text Added to the body"); //creating the text node
    document.body.appendChild(par.appendChild(text)); //appending the text to paragraph and appending the paragraph to the body.
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_createtextnode) for the example.

Answer (score 0):

I have re written your code below:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Number guessing game</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var par = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode("fhsgdjrs hgrtsfya");
  par.appendChild(text);
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(par);
</script>

</html>
```

This will work for you